# Difficulty with Group By

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

Im having some trouble understanding what I should do in this situation:

When ran, the query displays an item number, order quantity, the order date, and the salesman who documented the order.

```
SELECT t1.item_num,
       t2.qty_ordered,
       t2.order_date,
       t3.slsperson

FROM   t1
JOIN   t2
  ON   t1.item = t2.item
JOIN   t3
  ON   t2.order_num = t3.order_num
```

However, there are multiples of the same item number being returned with each one having different quantities ordered. I would like to group the similar item numbers to get the total qty ordered for that item.

I can't really group by item_num because nothing else in the SELECT has an aggregate function, and they aren't supposed to have one.

If the remaining columns don't have aggregate functions, how can I group the item numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understood correctly but I think this might be what you're after. You can group by all columns except the aggregate.

```
SELECT t1.item_num,
       sum(t2.qty_ordered),
       t2.order_date,
       t3.slsperson
FROM   
  t1
  JOIN   t2
    ON   t1.item = t2.item
  JOIN   t3
    ON   t2.order_num = t3.order_num
GROUP BY t1.item_num, t2.order_date, t3.slsperson
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just had a huge 'duh' moment. Your suggestion worked.

Comment: You're most welcome. I remember I didn't know how to do this as well. So simple when you finally find out!

Comment: @Anthony Sims, please mark the question as the correct answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.item_num,
   t2.qty_ordered,
   t2.order_date,
   t3.slsperson FROM t1 JOIN   t2 ON   t1.item = t2.item JOIN t3 ON t2.order_num = t3.order_num ) AS table GROUP BY table.item_num
```

hope it will works for you.